# Nested attribute localization for error messages in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, carrierwave, nested-attributes

I am using CarrierWave to upload the images.

i have 2 models

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_attachments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_attachments,   allow_destroy:        true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['image'].blank?}
end


class BookAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  has_many :images

  validates :image,
    :file_size => { 
    :maximum => 3.megabytes.to_i
  }

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

i need to localize the validation message for image size validation.

i give like the following in the en.yml:

```
en:  
  activerecord:    
    errors:
      models:
        book_attachment:
          attributes:
            image:
              too_big: The image is too big. The maximum size is 3 MB
```

The following message will get by default if image size is more: 
    "Book attachments image is too big (should be at most 3 MB)".

But. i need to get the message shown in the en.yml file.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
en:  
  activerecord:    
    errors:
      models:
        book_attachment:
          attributes:
            image:
              size_too_big: "is too big (should be at most 3 MB)"
```

The above worked for me . Thanks @Youri for the help. i used activerecord instead of activemodel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've implemented the custom validator from the wiki (https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Validate-attachment-file-size).

Try this:

```
en:
  activemodel:
    errors:
      models:
        book_attachment:
          attributes:
            image:
              size_too_big: "The image is too big. The maximum size is %{file_size} MB"
```

Alternatively you could also try a validation on the model directly:

```
class BookAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  has_many :images

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validate :image_size

  def image_size
    if image.file.size.to_i > 3.megabytes.to_i
      errors.add(:image, :size_too_big)
    end
  end
end
```